# Could not load file or assembly 'NDde

Tags: c#

a problem for showing Mozilla Firefox history in windows application c#

`Could not load file or assembly 'NDde, Version=2.1.563.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified`.